# Sourcing Parts for an Air:Bit Micro:Bit Drone

Tags: flight-controller, resources, online-resources

I am interested in the makekit air:bit drone as a first build, since I have a small 3d printer and already own 2 micro:bits. I am sourcing parts and noticed it has a custom controller board by makekit and SPRacing.

I can not find a place to buy this board on its own and only see places to purchase a full kit including things I don't need.

Has anybody made an Air:Bit that knows how to find the controller board on its own.

Here is more information about the project:
https://www.makekit.no/airbit

Does anybody have a good BOM with some links?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide us with some more context for what this project is? I'm not sure.

Comment: @ifconfig I linked out to the homepage of the project

Comment: Well, it appears from the URL that first-party designs are only available through their own distribution system. I have no idea if anyone has published bootleg BOMs or otherwise.

Comment: I contacted makekit directly to see what they say. At https://makekit.no/docs you can find documents that can help create your own BOM, but I still need to find a way to source the controller on its own to be complete.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't appear to me that they have made gerber files available for their custom PCBs. I see code, but not PCB CAD.

Comment: Ah. Yes good point. At some point I thought they had a GitHub that had a fairly complete set that included all that. Not sure if I remember correctly but I looked for it and can’t find it anymore.

Comment: Hrm, wouldn't that be interesting! Well, if that was correct you could order the SMD parts and PCB separately from a service online. I there that there are PCB assembly services available too if SMD isn't fun.

Comment: I also contacted SPRacing. The docs say that MakeKit produced the board with SPRacing as a collaborator.